# Firebase securityrules. How to allow access for admins stored in an array inside document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firebase firestore document where I store the admin ids in an *admins* array. How can I create security rules that allows reads and writes if a request userid is in that admins list.

I wonder about 3 cases:

1. If I have this rule how do I also allow an admin to write and read:

   ```
   match /users/{uid}{
     allow read,write: if request.auth != null;
   }
   ```
2. Can I make a function for example *isAdmin()* inside the securityrules which I can use in every rule to accept admin?
3. Is it possible to make **one** (or **two**) rules that allows the admins to read and write everything in the database, instead of writing a rule for every collection?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes to all three questions:

1. You can use the `||` operator
2. Yes, functions are allowed!
3. Yes, rules are inheritted top down

I very much so recommend these two videos:

- [Security Rules!  | Get to know Cloud Firestore #6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw)
- [Intermediate topics in Firebase Security Rules - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Mzb9zmnbJs)

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAdmin() {
      let admins = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/admins);
      return request.auth.uid in admins.data.users;
    }
    function isOwner() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin();
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if isAdmin() || isOwner();
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This rendered success for me in my test db
[image]
[image]

If you haven't used the rules playground yet, it's a good place to get started:
[image]

Comment: Upvoted (and abandoned my own answer).  
I'd have upvoted for the beautiful use of `let` alone already. :)
Btw: I typically have an `isOwner` function for the `request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId`, so that the main rule becomes `isOwner() || isAdmin()`

Comment: Thanks! I love the isOwner() idea, that cleans things up even more!